# Regarding linked list 3 element

Tags: java, data-structures

I am a new bie to the world of data structures and learning it , I have a query with regard to linked list , as in one of the interview it was asked with context to linked list is How to find 3rd element from end in a linked list in one pass, I have no idea for this Please advise.

Comment: With a java.util.LinkedList: linkedList.get(linkedList.size() - 3)

Comment: @JBNizet could you please show the updated code,Thanks

Comment: it is llinkedList.size() not linkedList.length() ..

Comment: @JBNizet is it not linkedList.size()?? don't think there is a length() method for Linked List, or is there?

Comment: @JBNizet Please specify the algorithm in simple steps

Comment: This is the only step you need. You have a linked list, and you ask it to get the element at `linkedList.size() - 3`, and it returns it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first node in you list I am assuming is called head.

So set a pointer to head, we'll call it current

```
Node current = head;
```

Then make another pointer that points three positions ahead

```
Node threeAhead = head.next.next.next;
```

Then write a loop that first checks to see if threeAhead.next is null, if it is not:

```
threeAhead = threeAhead.next;
curr = curr.next;
```

When threeAhead.next becomes null, you are three positions from the end with current.

Comment: But that makes almost 3 passes. Not just 1.

Comment: @JBNizet One pass means the first time through the full list. Or, find the third to last element without having knowledge of the number of items in the list.

Comment: With so few details in the question, it's impossible to give a good answer. If what you're after is performance, not storing the size of the list is counterproductive.

Comment: @BredttD Thanks a lot, Could you please show a small example , let say my linked list is head -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 then please advise how the above algorithm will work and how many passes would it require.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
if(node.next.next.next == null)
```

It's a little dirty, but basically I'd just check whether the node 3 nodes further down the line is null. If it is, you've got the 3rd one from the end. Ofcourse this is without accounting for a list with a size smaller than 3.

Comment: this  could lead to nullpointerexceptions if any of the previous nodes.next are null.

Comment: If the size of the linkedlist is 3 or above, it won't. Assuming none of the nodes are touched while looping obviously.

Comment: Of course if we assume that, but I guess.. this will be safer, right?  if(node != null && node.next != null && node.next.next != null && node.next.next == null)

Comment: `node` refers to the current node. I have stated the assumption that the size of the list will not be smaller than 3. Therefore it is given that the first 3 nodes will have a `next` value different from null. At this point you can start looping: `node.next.next.next` will be safe from NPE because we have previously stated the first 3 nodes will have a `next` value. Each iteration in the loop the `node` value will shift one spot, thus still leaving only one point of failure before moving on.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: this doesn't make one pass. It does almost 3.

Comment: Agree.. @JBNizet 's comment is the best approach

Comment: @JBNizet: I was under the assumption that `one pass` meant the entire loop could only be traversed once, and not necessarily one statement which should yield the result. Considering he accepted the answer of someone else having my solution, I guess that's what he meant. But I agree your solution is a lot cleaner ofcourse.

Comment: To me, one pass doesn't mean with just one statement. It means that every node should be visited at most once. Your solution visits almost every node three times. But the question is so bad that it's impossible to give a good answer.

Comment: You're correct, I overlooked this.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the length of the list is before you start, use JB Nizet's approach

```
node = first;
for (i = 0; i < length - N_FROM_END; i++) {
    node = node.next;
}

result = node.value
```

If you don't now the length:

```
nodes = new Node[N_FROM_END];
node = first;
for (i = 0; node != null; i++) {
    nodes[i % N_FROM_END] = node;
    node = node.next;
}
result = nodes[i % N_FROM_END].value
```

or something like that.  (Check the boundary conditions ... and account for the list length being less than `N_FROM_END`.)

Both answers satisfies the "visit nodes at most once" constraint.